# Save JSON Decode to MySQL , PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Good Day Please can you assist I'm trying to update a mysql table with a JSON POST. The JSON output into a textfile fine but when I try and save it to the MySQL table then supplies an error:

> Undefined index: ptp.create

The JSON Outputs the data as:

```
{"ptp.create":["629","630"]}

$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$myFile = "NewFile.txt";
file_put_contents($myFile,$jsonString);

$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

foreach ($data as $row){
$PTP = $row['ptp.create'];
$query_rsTable1 = "INSERT INTO test SET id = '$PTP'";
$rsTable1 = mysql_query($query_rsTable1, $int) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I'm not very 100% confident in JSON yet, if you could please assist.

Comment: The query should be `INSERT INTO test (column1, column2, ...) VALUES(value1, value2, ...)`. Here's more on that: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: do this steps, `1.read the json file contents 2.convert json object to php associative array3.Extract the Array Values4.Insert JSON to MySQL Database with PHP Code`

Comment: Be sure to use prepared/parameterized queries.  As-is right now, you're not escaping anything, which will lead to bugs and security issues.

Comment: @iSS OP's syntax is valid. He is using a deprecated and no longer valid mysql_* api but mysql syntax is ok.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta I stand corrected! Didn't know it was possible! Thank you!

Comment: you have `$data['ptp.create']` w/o looping, and can't put an array into the query string. `"INSERT INTO test SET id = '". mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($data['ptp.create'])) ."'"`

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop has already taken care of the `ptp.create` for you.

```
foreach ($data as $ptp){
  echo $ptp;  // Will be 629, then 630
}
```

When you actually insert into your database, use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.